# How to merge 2 separate Keras models sequentially?

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I have two pretrained tf.Keras models:

```
model = tf.keras.models.Sequential(name="EOS_Net")
model.add(tf.keras.Input(shape=(7,)))    
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation="relu"))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation="relu"))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation="relu"))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation="relu"))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation="relu"))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation="relu"))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(30))
```

and

```py
inputA=tf.keras.Input(shape=(30,1))

x = tf.keras.layers.Conv1D(32,2,strides=1,padding = 'same',kernel_initializer='he_normal',
  kernel_regularizer=tf.keras.regularizers.l2(0.0000001),activation='elu')(inputA)

...

x = tf.keras.layers.Conv1D(2,1,strides=1,padding = 'same',kernel_initializer='he_normal',
kernel_regularizer=tf.keras.regularizers.l2(0.0000001),activation='sigmoid')(x)

model = tf.keras.Model(inputA, x)
```

In the end, I want a new model that acts like:

```
out = Model2(Model1(input))
```

but as one big model that can do auto diff with `tf.GradientTape()`.

What's the best way to get there ?